# Apply function to nested loop (purrr package?)

Tags: r, purrr

This should be simple, but I can't work it out ...

I want to apply a function, eg. mean to each of the lower lists,
eg. I want to return

> $`1`
>
> $`1`$a  [1] value_of_mean 1
>
> $`1`$b  [1] value_of_mean 2
>
> $`2`
>
> $`2`$a  [1] value_of_mean 3
>
> $`2`$b  [1] value_of_mean 4

I am trying to use the purrr package

```
require(purrr)    
mylist <- list("1"=list(a=runif(10), b=runif(10)), "2"=list(a=runif(10), b=runif(10)))
        map(mylist, mean)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `map` twice, as `modify_depth` was introduced to tidy-up the double `map` call.

```
library(purrr)

set.seed(123)

mylist <- list("1"=list(a=runif(10), b=runif(10)), "2"=list(a=runif(10), b=runif(10)))

modify_depth(mylist, 2, mean)
```

resulting in:

```
> modify_depth(mylist, 2, mean)
$`1`
$`1`$a
[1] 0.5782475

$`1`$b
[1] 0.5233693


$`2`
$`2`$a
[1] 0.6155837

$`2`$b
[1] 0.537858
```

This is the same as

```
mylist %>% map(~ map(.x, mean))
```

resulting in:

```
> mylist %>% map(~ map(.x, mean))
$`1`
$`1`$a
[1] 0.5782475

$`1`$b
[1] 0.5233693


$`2`
$`2`$a
[1] 0.6155837

$`2`$b
[1] 0.537858
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call `map` twice to accomplish this. This will work through each list in the top-level list and perform the mean on each element of that top-level list, i.e., the bottom-level lists:

```
mylist %>% map(~ map(.x, mean))
```

that gives you this:

```
$`1`
$`1`$a
[1] 0.5734347

$`1`$b
[1] 0.5321065


$`2`
$`2`$a
[1] 0.483521

$`2`$b
[1] 0.5138651
```